# Conditional nested block in Terraform resource

Tags: terraform

Given this resource:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
    ...
    network_interface {
        ...
        access_config {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to conditionally define the `access_config` property based on a condition.

#### [Edit] Solution

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
    ...
    network_interface {
        ...
        dynamic "access_config" {
            for_each = var.condition ? [1] : []
            content {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please update with the results of your dynamic nested block? Also, this may end up being an issue on the Terraform Github tracker.

Comment: Actually I discovered that the syntax that I wrote is correct! My IDE was simply complaining and I assumed there was something wrong...  my bad!

Answer (score 4):

Similar to what `Josep Nadal` mentioned, but change `count` to `for_each` like

```
  dynamic "access_config" {
    for_each = var.conditional_on ? ["1"] : []
    content {
      nat_ip = null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar, but I think you can accomplish this using the count parameter.

First you need to add a variable into your variables.tf file:

```
variable "conditional_on" {
  description = "enable or disable"
  type        = bool
}
```

Then you can add the count parameter with the variable:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
    ...
    network_interface {
        ...
        dynamic "access_config" {
            count = var.conditional_on ? 1 : 0
            content {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is more information on the Terraform Documentation:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#conditionals

Comment: Either I am missing something or dynamic blocks don't support `count`

Comment: did anyone found answer for this ?

Comment: for me only works with for each, not with count